# Refactoring a Scala Code to Avoid Duplication

Tags: scala

I have the following code that does some pattern matching and returns a response accordingly:

```
def handleProvisioningServiceCSRequests(provisioningCsRequest: ProvisioningCSRequest, chargingStationId: String, msgTypeId: Int, msgId: String): Future[OCPPCallResponse] = provisioningCsRequest match {
    case bootNotificationRequest: BootNotificationRequest => provisioningService.bootNotification(bootNotificationRequest, chargingStationId).runToFuture.materialize.map {
      case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
      case Success(response) => OCPPCallResult(
        messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
        messageId = msgId,
        payload = Json.toJson(response)
      )
    }
    case notifyReportRequest: NotifyReportRequest => provisioningService.notifyReport(notifyReportRequest, chargingStationId).runToFuture.materialize.map {
      case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
      case Success(response) => OCPPCallResult(
        messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
        messageId = msgId,
        payload = Json.toJson(response)
      )
    }
  }
```

As it can be seen that the preparation off the OCPPCallError or the OCPPCallResult is repetitive and kind of the same. I will have to do 10 other pattern match case statements and that means 10 times repetition.

I tried refactoring it like this below, but it obviously fails compilation as it says it cannot find implicit conversions:

```
def handleProvisioningServiceCSRequests(provisioningCsRequest: ProvisioningCSRequest, chargingStationId: String, msgTypeId: Int, msgId: String): Future[OCPPCallResponse] = {
    val result = provisioningCsRequest match {
      case bootNotificationRequest: BootNotificationRequest => provisioningService.bootNotification(bootNotificationRequest, chargingStationId).runToFuture
      case notifyReportRequest: NotifyReportRequest => provisioningService.notifyReport(notifyReportRequest, chargingStationId).runToFuture
    }
    result.materialize.map {
      case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
      case Success(response) => OCPPCallResult(
        messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
        messageId = msgId,
        payload = Json.toJson(response)) // Fails here saying it cannot find implicits for Writes[Product with Serializable]
    }
  }
```

The response in the Success(response) does not add up. How can I cope  up for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious fix would be to ensure that result already contains the converted Json by moving the Json-encoding into the upper pattern match:

```
def handleProvisioningServiceCSRequests(provisioningCsRequest: ProvisioningCSRequest, chargingStationId: String, msgTypeId: Int, msgId: String): Future[OCPPCallResponse] = {
    val result = provisioningCsRequest match {
      case bootNotificationRequest: BootNotificationRequest => 
        provisioningService.bootNotification(bootNotificationRequest, chargingStationId)
          .runToFuture.map(response => Json.toJson(response))
      case notifyReportRequest: NotifyReportRequest => 
        provisioningService.notifyReport(notifyReportRequest, chargingStationId)
          .runToFuture.map(response => Json.toJson(response))
    }
    result.materialize.map {
      case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
      case Success(json) => OCPPCallResult(
        messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
        messageId = msgId,
        payload = json
    }
  }
```

Since you're aiming at reducing redundancies, you might also want to move the `runToFuture` down into the shared part of the code:

```
def handleProvisioningServiceCSRequests(provisioningCsRequest: ProvisioningCSRequest, chargingStationId: String, msgTypeId: Int, msgId: String): Future[OCPPCallResponse] = {
    val result = provisioningCsRequest match {
      case bootNotificationRequest: BootNotificationRequest => 
        provisioningService.bootNotification(bootNotificationRequest, chargingStationId)
          .map(response => Json.toJson(response))
      case notifyReportRequest: NotifyReportRequest => 
        provisioningService.notifyReport(notifyReportRequest, chargingStationId)
          .map(response => Json.toJson(response))
    }
    result.runToFuture.materialize.map {
      case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
      case Success(json) => OCPPCallResult(
        messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
        messageId = msgId,
        payload = json
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, a more involved solution would be to introduce a helper function that abstracts over the type of the result and the availability of an implicit `Writes` instance for it (not 100% sure if this will compile like this because I'm making quite a few assumptions about the libraries that are being used (e.g. assuming that your `provisioningService` returns `monix.eval.Task`s)):

```
def handleProvisioningServiceCSRequests(provisioningCsRequest: ProvisioningCSRequest, chargingStationId: String, msgTypeId: Int, msgId: String): Future[OCPPCallResponse] = {
    def handleResult[T: Writes](result: Task[T]): Future[OCPPCallResponse] =
      result.runToFuture.materialize.map {
        case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
        case Success(json) => OCPPCallResult(
          messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
          messageId = msgId,
          payload = Json.toJson(response)
      }
    provisioningCsRequest match {
      case bootNotificationRequest: BootNotificationRequest =>
        handleResult(provisioningService.bootNotification(bootNotificationRequest, chargingStationId))
      case notifyReportRequest: NotifyReportRequest => 
        handleResult(provisioningService.notifyReport(notifyReportRequest, chargingStationId))
    }
  }
```

Edit: if all of your cases are handled in the way that you call a specific method of the `provisioningService` that takes the specific request and the `chargingStationId`, then you could make this even less redundant (at the price of making it more verbose). Not sure what type the `provisioningService` has, so in this example, I name the type `ProvisioningService`:

```
def handleProvisioningServiceCSRequests(provisioningCsRequest: ProvisioningCSRequest, chargingStationId: String, msgTypeId: Int, msgId: String): Future[OCPPCallResponse] = {
    def executeRequest[T: Writes](f: ProvisoningService => String => Task[T]): Future[OCPPCallResponse] =
      f(provisoningService)(chargingStationId).runToFuture.materialize.map {
        case Failure(fail) => populateOCPPCallError(msgId, msgTypeId, OCPPCallErrorCode.InternalError(), fail.getMessage)
        case Success(json) => OCPPCallResult(
          messageTypeId = msgTypeId,
          messageId = msgId,
          payload = Json.toJson(response)
      }
    provisioningCsRequest match {
      case bootNotificationRequest: BootNotificationRequest => 
        executeRequest(_.bootNotification(bootNotificationRequest, _))
      case notifyReportRequest: NotifyReportRequest => 
        executeRequest(_.notifyReport(notifyReportRequest, _))
    }
  }
```

Comment: That fails  diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Writes[com.openelectrons.ocpp.messages.v20.BootNotificationResponse]
[error] starting with method rangeWrites in trait DefaultWrites

Comment: It is really wierd that now even my original version which had duplicate lines is not compiling anymore and fails for the same reason - diverging implicit expansion!

Comment: That's certainly a different problem than the refactoring question at hand. You should ask yourself where the `Writes`-instances (that implement the conversion to json) for your response-types are implemented. Maybe those `Writes`-implementations are still missing?

Comment: There was a strange import from the Play JSON library that was causing this issue, Somehow the GenericFormat was part of some import and as soon as I removed it, the problem went away. Need to be careful with what I import, especially when dealing with lot of implicits.